# XSl-FO Repeating values in table - version 1.0

Tags: xsl-fo

Using xsl-fo Creating one report which will generate PDF file based upon FO file.
Problem:
If you see below code i have created Detail Area with Columns and Row Separator(Grid view, frame yes).
Its working Fine but whenever i use XML Node Path and give path to a Detail Area then TOTAL(its a row) gets repeated after every record as you can see in Image.
i want some thing which will stop them repeating.

```
          <xsl:for-each  select="DOCUMENT/ROWSET/ROW[count(. |             key('bykey1453107264684', ORDER_ID)[1]) = 1]">
<fo:table-row  keep-with-next="always"  background-color="#ffffff"  height="3.43cm"   >
    <fo:table-cell>
    <!-- b7241a65976545a29cb3adaf7e81d5ab -->
        <fo:block  keep-together="always"><xsl:value-of select="LINE_NO"></xsl:value-of></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell  >
    <!-- 6193eb7f045b4c7f84a62ec78f9b8610 -->
    <fo:block    keep-together="always" ><xsl:value-of select="PARTICULAR"></xsl:value-of></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell >
    <!-- b851391f97d943ae8ea9ad24544887fd -->
    <fo:block  keep-together="always"><xsl:value-of select="TOTAL_AMT">               </xsl:value-of></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block></fo:block>        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row keep-together="always" >
    <fo:table-cell  >
    <fo:block></fo:block>        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell  >
    <!-- 6a4ae7636f7240cfb324c03b7ff502ac -->
    <fo:block   keep-together="always">Total</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell  >
    <!-- efcabc0ed27b4db397079743e4caee5f -->
    <fo:block  keep-together="always"><xsl:value-of select="LINE_TOTAL_AMT"></xsl:value-of></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block></fo:block>        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
    </xsl:if>


    <!-- END Area Detail -->
    </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
```

1)The way i wanted:

[image]

2)After giving xnodepath :

[image]

3)xnode:

[image]

Apology if something missing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the software you are using, so I don't know how to do it, but you need to move the second `fo:table-row` out of the `xsl:for-each`:

```
<xsl:for-each  select="DOCUMENT/ROWSET/ROW[count(. |             key('bykey1453107264684', ORDER_ID)[1]) = 1]">
  <fo:table-row  keep-with-next="always"  background-color="#ffffff"  height="3.43cm"   >
    <fo:table-cell>
      <!-- b7241a65976545a29cb3adaf7e81d5ab -->
      <fo:block  keep-together="always"><xsl:value-of select="LINE_NO"></xsl:value-of></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell  >
      <!-- 6193eb7f045b4c7f84a62ec78f9b8610 -->
      <fo:block    keep-together="always" ><xsl:value-of select="PARTICULAR"></xsl:value-of></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell >
      <!-- b851391f97d943ae8ea9ad24544887fd -->
      <fo:block  keep-together="always"><xsl:value-of select="TOTAL_AMT">               </xsl:value-of></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block></fo:block>        </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
<fo:table-row keep-together="always" >
  <fo:table-cell  >
  <fo:block></fo:block>        </fo:table-cell>
  <fo:table-cell  >
    <!-- 6a4ae7636f7240cfb324c03b7ff502ac -->
    <fo:block   keep-together="always">Total</fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
  <fo:table-cell  >
    <!-- efcabc0ed27b4db397079743e4caee5f -->
    <fo:block  keep-together="always"><xsl:value-of select="LINE_TOTAL_AMT"></xsl:value-of></fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
  <fo:table-cell>
  <fo:block></fo:block>        </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
</xsl:if>


<!-- END Area Detail -->
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```